# Thunderbird - automatically convert URLs to links

Tags: thunderbird, url, links

I'd like Thunderbird to convert URLs to links automatically. I get hundreds of system-generated messages from a customer which contain unlinked URLs. The same URLs are converted to links automatically by other e-mail clients.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the add-on [URL link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/url-link/?src=collection&collection_id=ca963acd-35ec-4ad4-0d62-46c2c7dbb53e).

Comment: Thanks berserck but that add-on doesn't really help me. I can already select the URLs and paste them into the address bar of my browser. What I'd like is for the URLs to be linked automatically so all I have to do is click on them